# How to build one migration in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have made one migration. How can I build only this file?

I tried:

```
 php artisan make:migration filename.php
 php artisan make:migration filename
 php artisan make:migration tablename
```

Comment: which file you want to build.is there any issues with above one.explain your problem. check laravel documentation `https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations`

Comment: I try to build miration, not create

Comment: you need to use  `php artisan make:migration create_filename_table`. you must use create_(your table name without space)_table.`php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users`

Comment: @Putin you have to listed to everybody. If you want the migration files be implemented in your db, then you have to run the `php artisan migrate` ugh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just actually do:

`php artisan make:migration the_name_of_your_migration_file --create=table_name`

Or if you want to update the existing table,

`php artisan make:migration add_column_to_existing_table --table=table_name`

This is in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations)

Comment: It creates migration file, but not table in database

Comment: of course you need to run the `php artisan migrate` don't you think?

Comment: `php artisan migrate` runs all migration in directory

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we can migrate using file names.

However, you can comment out the function to avoid them from running.

Also once you migrate and add new migration files, php artisan migrate will only run the new migrations, so you may do it one at time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use create_users_table.create and table must be used.

if you use below one.it will generate with schema

```
`php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users`
```

if you use below one . it will create with out schema

```
php artisan make:migration create_filename_table
```

the created table are present in database->migrations folder
 add which fields you want

In your migration table add

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->string('photo')->nullable();
            $table->enum('theme', array_values(config('myespaceadmin.application.themes')))->nullable();
            $table->boolean('status');
            $table->boolean('is_delete');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

finally in console `php artisan migrate`

Comment: All commands create only file migration without changes in db

Comment: you want to see table in your database you must do `php artisan migrate`.it will create table in your db

Comment: did you added configurations of your database in config->database.php

Comment: `php artisan migrate` works only when your migrations directory contains migrations tables